# ¿Alguien sabe como se hace esto en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

En esta web hay hecho un simulador para cambiar los colores y texturas en Javascript a una foto de un salón...
https://www.losan.es/es/melamina/simulador-3d?escenario=salon

Según entiendo como lo tienen hecho es generando todas las combinaciones posibles?, es así?
me resulta extraño que lo hayan hecho a mano.

¿Existe alguna otra manera de hacerlo?

muchas gracias

Comment: Piensa que la imagen puede estar hecha por partes, así que no seria muy descabellado que tengan las combinaciones pre hechas y luego junten los muebles.
Pero creo, que esta hecho en 3D, y esas texturas realmente solo tenga la información de las transparencias (para las sombras), y en JS le apliquen la textura.

Comment: Depende de lo que entiendas por "hacerlo a mano". Eso no es una foto, es un render. Y en un software como los cad de arquitectura puedes darle un acabado con texturas a cualquier superficie. En ese sitio cuando pinchas un material lo que hace es cargar otra foto. Por ejemplo pasa de https://www.losan.es/simulador/img/simulador-2-240-380.jpg a https://www.losan.es/simulador/img/simulador-2-92-102.jpg. Esas no se generaron a mano. Lo hicieron con un batch desde el renderizador, pero en ese sitio ya están pregeneradas.

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta para que otros puedan beneficiarce de tú pregunta y las respuestas aquí planteadas.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por favor, si te funciono la repuesta recuerda "ACEPTAR" para que otros Usuarios se beneficien de ella.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que utilices siempre el inspector de tu navegador, vas a descubrir cosas interesantes...

Esto fue lo que encontre (y si lo hace manual)...Cuando presiona el boton de capa (el central) llama a un modal hecho en Bootstrap, luego cuando selecciona una textura carga una funcion llamada cargarimagenCapa(x,x) y le pasa dos parametros que son capa y acabado.

Aqui esta todo el script incluyendo la funcion que te mencione.

Espero que te sirva.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        })
        function reposicionarBotones() {
            // entra en este if si la pantalla es vertical y la imagen se ajusta a la parte superior mostrando espacio vacío en la parte inferior
            if (((window.innerWidth * 1335) / 2000) < window.innerHeight) {
                $("div[id^='capa-background-']").css('background-position','top center');
                
                // centra los botones de la derecha en el centro de la imagen
                $('#capaBotonesMaster').addClass('capaBotonesMasterConDesfase');
                $('#capaBotonesMaster').css('top',((window.innerWidth * 1335) / 2000) / 2);
                
                // 500 es la coordenada y del botón 1
                var topActual1 = (500 * ((window.innerWidth * 1335) / 2000)) / 1335;
                $('#botonCapas1').css('top',topActual1);
                // 1100 es la coordenada y del botón 2
                var topActual2 = (1100 * ((window.innerWidth * 1335) / 2000)) / 1335;
                $('#botonCapas2').css('top',topActual2);
            } else {
                $('#capaBotonesMaster').removeClass('capaBotonesMasterConDesfase');
                
                $("div[id^='capa-background-']").css('background-position','center center');
                // 500 es la coordenada y del botón 1
                var topActual1 = (500 * window.innerHeight) / 1335;
                $('#botonCapas1').css('top',topActual1);
                // 1100 es la coordenada y del botón 2
                var topActual2 = (1100 * window.innerHeight) / 1335;
                $('#botonCapas2').css('top',topActual2);
            }
            
            // 710 es la coordenada x del botón 1
            var leftActual1 = (710 * window.innerWidth) / 2000;
            $('#botonCapas1').css('left',leftActual1);
            // 1650 es la coordenada x del botón 2
            var leftActual2 = (1650 * window.innerWidth) / 2000;
            $('#botonCapas2').css('left',leftActual2);
        }
        reposicionarBotones();
        $(window).resize(function() {
            reposicionarBotones();
        });
    });
        
        // imágenes
        var img1_actual = 240;
        var img2_actual = 380;
        
        function cargarImagenCapa(capa, acabado) {
            // generamos posible imagen
            if(capa == 1) {
                img1_actual = acabado;
                }
            else if(capa == 2) {
                img2_actual = acabado;
                }
            
            generaImagen(capa, acabado);
            }
        
        function cargaImagenSimulador(capa, acabado) {
            if(capa == 1) capa_bis = 2;
            else capa_bis = 1;
            
            // if que controla sin el acabado en el que se ha hecho clic es el que está ya mostrado, en ese caso simplemente cierra el modal
            if ($('#capa-background-' + capa + '-' + img1_actual + '-' + img2_actual).hasClass('actual-' + capa)) {
                $('#modalAcabados-' + capa).modal('hide');
            } else {
                $('#modalAcabados-' + capa).modal('hide');
                
                // si llega aquí es que el acabado seleccionado es diferente al actual, en ese caso se oculta el actual
                $('.actual-' + capa).each(function() {
                    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
                    $(this).removeClass('actual-' + capa);
                });
                
                $('.acabadoActual-' + capa).each(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('acabadoActual-' + capa);
                });
                
                // capa bis
                $('.actual-' + capa_bis).each(function() {
                    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
                    $(this).removeClass('actual-' + capa_bis);
                });
                
                // forzamos a que se muestre la imagen de la capa 2 para evitar que la imagen a mostrar pueda ser que quede por detrás
                capa = 2;
                
                // si el acabado ha sido cargado ya previamente no hace falta hacer loading de la imagen, simplemente se hace aparecer esa imagen
                if ($('#capa-background-' + capa + '-' + img1_actual + '-' + img2_actual).hasClass('yaCargado')) {
                    $('#capa-background-' + capa + '-' + img1_actual + '-' + img2_actual).addClass('actual-' + capa);
                    $('#miniaturaAcabado-' + capa + '-' + acabado).addClass('acabadoActual-' + capa);
                    $('#capa-background-' + capa + '-' + img1_actual + '-' + img2_actual).fadeIn("slow");
                // se llega aquí si la imagen de la capa que hay que mostrar no se ha cargado previamente, en ese caso se llama al lazy para cargarla
                } else {
                    $('#capa-background-' + capa + '-' + img1_actual + '-' + img2_actual).css('display','block');
                    $('#capa-background-' + capa + '-' + img1_actual + '-' + img2_actual).addClass('yaCargado actual-' + capa);
                    $('#miniaturaAcabado-' + capa + '-' + acabado).addClass('acabadoActual-' + capa);
                    $('.lazy-' + capa + '-' + img1_actual + '-' + img2_actual).Lazy({
                        onFinishedAll: function() {
                            $('#capa-background-' + capa + '-' + img1_actual + '-' + img2_actual).removeClass('capaConLoading');
                            $('#capa-background-' + capa + '-' + img1_actual + '-' + img2_actual).removeClass('lazy-' + capa + '-' + img1_actual + '-' + img2_actual);
                        },
                        effect: "fadeIn",
                        effectTime: 500
                    });
                }
            }
        
        document.getElementById('informacionActualImg-1').src = document.getElementById('miniaturaAcabado-1-' + img1_actual).src;
        $('#informacionActual-1').text($('#denominacionAcabado-1-' + img1_actual).text());
        
        document.getElementById('informacionActualImg-2').src = document.getElementById('miniaturaAcabado-2-' + img2_actual).src;
        $('#informacionActual-2').text($('#denominacionAcabado-2-' + img2_actual).text());
        }   // function cargaImagenSimulador()
    
        // Función que genera la imagen oportuna
        var id_escenario = 2;
        
        function generaImagen(capa, acabado) {
            // alert(img1_actual + ' : ' + img2_actual)
            
            url_consulta = 'https://www.losan.es/simulador.generaImg.php';
            
            var dataString = 'ide=' + id_escenario + '&idp1=' + img1_actual + '&idp2=' + img2_actual;
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url_consulta,
                data: dataString,
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    //$("#boton").val('Connecting...');
                    },
                success: function(data) {
                    retorno = $.parseJSON(data)
                    
                    if($.trim(retorno.resultado) == "ok") {
                        cargaImagenSimulador(capa, acabado);
                        }
                    //else if($.trim(data) == "error") {
                    else {
                        // alert('KO');
                        }
                    },
                error: function (request, error) {
                    // alert('Se han detectado errores. Por favor, inténtelo más tarde');
                    }
                });
            }   // function generaImagen()
        
        // Función que descarga el PDF con los datos del simulador actual
        function descargaSimulador() {
            if((img1_actual != 0) || (img2_actual != 0)) {
                var cadena = 'https://www.losan.es/simulador.generaPdf.php?ide=' + id_escenario + '&idp1=' + img1_actual + '&idp2=' + img2_actual;
                self.location = cadena;
                }
            }
```